# Including one PHP file in another

Tags: php

**How can I go from one *.php file to another *.php file** ? For example, if I have this in `index.php`:

```
<?php 
 <form method="POST" action="second.php">
 <input type="button" name="GO">
 </form>
?>
```

and this in `second.php`:

```
  <?php
    if ($_POST['GO'])
         // HERE SHOULD BE CODE LIKE "INCLUDE" OR SOMETHING TO GO TO index.php
  ?>
```

I have tried `include('index.php');`, but it doesn't work at all. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why is your `<form>` wrapped in `<?php` tags `?>`?

Comment: if ($_POST['GO'])

should be if(!empty($_POST['GO']))

Comment: @thirsty93: or better if( isset($_POST['GO']) )

Comment: @erenon: or even better `if (array_key_exists('GO', $_POST))`

Comment: This question is not very precise ... What do you mean with "going from one file to another" EXACTLY? I assume you want your form to work which does not because you used the type "button" instead of "submit".

Comment: @Ivan: I don't see how this would be better:

1. It's longer than isset(...)
2. It is not as self-explanatory because it is not visually showing that 'GO' is a key of the $_POST-array - You have to carefully read the code to see that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean a redirect?

```
header('Location: index.php');
exit;
```

Comment: For that to work you'll need to not have already started outputting data to the client, otherwise PHP will yell at you.